# Bootstrap dateTime picker is not working and not showing properly as well

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, momentjs, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

In my page I am using jQuery multidate Picker in two input fields and on some other input field I am using bootstrap dateTime picker. But I am facing many issues-

1)**Boostrap dateTime picker is not working properly not showing in proper place where I wants and showing error in console is**
    "uncaught typeerror: cannot read property 'top' of undefined"

2)**When I am giving reference of library as full URL then only its working but when I am giving reference from my JS and CSS library folders its showing error in console as-**
   $(....).datetimepicker is not a function.

URL ---Bootstrap dateTime picker

```
<link href="https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group  col-md-4 col-sm-4 txtnew  col-xs-6">
        <label for="date">Date:</label> <br />
        <s:textfield type="text" readonly="true" id="createDate" 
         name="createDate"class="form-control" autocomplete="off"/>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#createDate').datetimepicker();
});
</script>
```

[screenshot of error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urwf9.png)

Please help me I searched a lot but not able to resolve it.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: u might need to drop the jquery ui datepicker and use other datepicker as replacement

Comment: @Se0ng11 Thanks for the suggestion but what about point 2 the error is showing in console?

Comment: you need to show ur script for ppl to know what actually goes wrong, we can't guess what is the issue

Comment: @Se0ng11 see my post I added HTML and JS part as well and a screenshot of console in which I am getting error. I hope through this you will get clarity.

Comment: there might be conflict of bootstrap datepicker and jquery datepicker, remove ur multidatepicker from ur page and test it out, and it is best to always run ur boostrap.js b4 other js

Comment: @Se0ng11 I removed the other Libraries just using now Bootstrap libraries of dateTime picker. Still getting error in console  "uncaught typeerror: cannot read property 'top' of undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please refer to the below jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/hd75xoky/1/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" id='createDate' name="createDate" readonly />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
 $(function () {
     $('#createDate').datetimepicker({
       ignoreReadonly: true
     });
 });
```

it seem that the reference of your link is causing the issue, as I link it using the reference that you post, it hit the same error that you had face, below is the reference that I use from cdnjs, feel free to have a look

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```